# Stop PHP parsing but output the rest of the file

Tags: php

I'm developing a web application where an html page is created for the user. The page could include anything that the user puts in it. We take these pages and add a little PHP at the top to check some things before outputting the actual html. It would look kind of like this:

```
<?php
    require 'checksomestuff.php';

    // User's html below
?>

<html>
    <!-- user's html -->
</html>
```

Is there a way to stop PHP from parsing anything after my `require`? I need the html to be outputted, but, since the user can add anything they want to the html, I don't want any user-added PHP to be executed. Obviously that would be a security issue. So, I want the user's html to be outputted, but not parse any PHP. I would rather not have to put the user's html into another file.

Comment: If you don't want the page to include user-created PHP, then don't allow the user to enter PHP code that will be processed by the page....

Comment: How will the users add the HTML?

Comment: you have completely misunderstood the security concepts.. you need to check the user's input for vulnerability rather than not displaying/executing them..

Comment: You are doing it wrong, and procedural way. Rethink your concept.

Answer (score 1):

One sensible way would be to offload the user created content to another file and then you should load this file (in your main php file) and output it as is - without parsing it as PHP.

There are many other ways to do this but if creating another file does the job for you then thats probably the best way forward.

**UPDATE**: Really must read last line of question!

You could encode the html into a variable using base64 encoding which you then just print out the decoded string.

Comment: "I would rather not have to put the user's html into another file." But thanks anyway.

Comment: @MattBradley Ah, sorry about that. Added to answer another way of doing it.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't store the file data in a php file, say n a txt or html file, the php won't be evaluated.

Alternatively you could read the file via file_get_contents() or by some other means which doesn't involve evaluating php.

Comment: "I would rather not have to put the user's html into another file." But thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Though I'm still tempted to ask *why* you want to do this (particularly this way), it sounds to me like one of the only things that can help you is the special [`__halt_compiler()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.halt-compiler.php) function...

That *should* prevent it from executing the rest of the page, and may or may not output the rest of it. If not, well, read the first (and currently only) example in the PHP's manual for that function (linked above) for how to do it manually.

The only trouble I see with this method is that you'd probably have to have that code in every file you want to do this for, after your require.